# Storing and accessing a global flag/variable in each component, The value keeps changing

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to make a global service class which will store few variables which will influence behaviour on HTML components base on flags. 
My current only flag is a BehaviourSubject which navbar component subscribes to update a navbar with different buttons. The issue is when I refresh the page in a browser the flag reverse to the original value and forgets what has set before. The current scenario is when user log in the flag is being set to true and should stay true until a user logs out. It may not be a right way to do it so if there is a better way of approaching it; then I am happy to implement it.

Data sharing class:

```
import {
  Injectable
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  BehaviorSubject
} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class ServiceClassDatasharing {
  public isUserLoggedIn: BehaviorSubject < boolean > = new BehaviorSubject < boolean > (false);
  public setUserLoggedInStatus(status) {
    this.isUserLoggedIn.next(status);
  }
}
```

Nav Component:

```
import {
  Component,
  OnInit
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  MatDialog,
  MatDialogRef,
  MAT_DIALOG_DATA
} from '@angular/material';
import {
  Inject
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  ServiceClassDatasharing
} from '../service/service-class-datasharing';
import {
  ServiceClassAuth
} from '../service/service-class-auth';
import {
  SigninComponent
} from './../signin/signin.component';
import {
  Router
} from '@angular/router';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-nav',
  templateUrl: './nav.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./nav.component.css']
})
export class NavComponent implements OnInit {

  id_token: Boolean;
  username: String;

  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog, private dataSharingService: ServiceClassDatasharing,
    private authService: ServiceClassAuth, private router: Router) {

    this.dataSharingService.isUserLoggedIn.subscribe(res => {
      this.id_token = res;
      if (this.id_token) {
        const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
        this.username = user['user'].user_username;
      }
    });
    if (!this.id_token) {
      router.navigate(['index']);
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {}

  openDialog(): void {
    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(SigninComponent, {
      width: '450px',
      data: {}
    });
  }

  public logout() {
    this.authService.logout().subscribe(res => {
      if (res['success']) {
        localStorage.clear();
        this.dataSharingService.setUserLoggedInStatus(false);
      }
    });
    this.router.navigate(['index']);
  }

}
```

Index Component as an example it should redirect a user to dashboard if the global flag is set to true.

```
import {
  Component,
  OnInit
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  ServiceClassDatasharing
} from '../service/service-class-datasharing';

import {
  Router
} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-index',
  templateUrl: './index.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./index.component.css']
})
export class IndexComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private dataSharingService: ServiceClassDatasharing, private router: Router) {
    if (this.dataSharingService.isUserLoggedIn.value) {
      this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {}

}
```

Comment: try creating variable as constant, that wont change.

Comment: but I need to be able to update it to false/true base on user action would
 set it to constant would bascily make it a protected ?

Comment: why dont you use local storage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using *localStorage* variable to achieve the same .

Create a function in service class which will set the variable with token if user logs in and function to get the same token.

```
const key = 'abcde'

setUseLoggedIn(token){
 localStorage.setItem(this.key,token);
}

getUserLoggedIn(){
 return localStorage.getItem(this.key);
}
```

set token as null if user is not logged in and check for the same when retrieving the token.